# Auth0 allowLogIn and allowRegister

Tags: angular, ionic4, auth0

I have a web app and mobile app using same Auth0 application for login.
I have followed this Auth0 angular guide (https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login) and Auth0 Ionic3 guide (https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/ionic3/01-login) and everything works fine.

Now My app has two different buttons for login and registration. When login is clicked, I want to only show Auth0 login dialog and when register is clicked, I want to show only Auth0 registration.

As I am not using Auth0 Lock, allowLogin option does not work. I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this? Also, I will need to modify the Auth0 UI to match my app theme.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two ways to develop the app with our stack. You can either go for Lock which gives you a general UI that you can more or less customize based on your needs along with using the SDK it’s hitting proper API endpoints in the background etc etc (where you can make use of allowLogin)

The other approach requires more development work from your side as you will only be using our Authentication API hitting the right endpoints to handle login / signup / logout and with that solution you will need to build the UI itself (which you can build base on your project needs)

I hope this helps you in your path forward. Thanks!

Comment: I am happy to use Authentication API if they are javascript. I am building a progressive web app using Ionic hence I would need this to work on both mobile and web. Also, I have to use silent authentication in both mobile and web. Can you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score -1):

As you are using auth0-js sdk, it is possible to pass extra parameter in the hosted login page when calling **authoirze()** method.

Then, you can capture the extra parameter in the hosted login page and pass the parameter as lock configuration.

(Note that auth0 hosted login page uses lock as default login template). To achieve your goal, enable the customization in the hosted login page. 
https://auth0.com/docs/universal-login/advanced-customization

**Login:**

When the user clicks on the Login button in your application, pass a parameter to disable signup.

```
 var auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    clientID: environment.auth0.client_id,
    domain: environment.auth0.domain,
    responseType: environment.auth0.responseType,
    audience: environment.auth0.audience,
    redirectUri: environment.auth0.callbackurl,
    scope: environment.auth0.scope,
  });

  const params = {
      allow_signup:false,

    };
    this.auth0.authorize(params);
```

Then, in the hosted page, capture the extra parameter and pass to lock configuration option.

```
   //Access the addtional parameters in the hosted login page like below
    console.log(config.extraParams.allow_signup);

allowSignUp: config.extraParams.allow_signup
```

https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11/configuration#allowsignup-boolean-

**Registration:**

Apply the same technique for Sign up. Disable the login in Lock.

```
 var auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    clientID: environment.auth0.client_id,
    domain: environment.auth0.domain,
    responseType: environment.auth0.responseType,
    audience: environment.auth0.audience,
    redirectUri: environment.auth0.callbackurl,
    scope: environment.auth0.scope,
  });

  const params = {
      allow_login:false,

    };
    this.auth0.authorize(params);
```

Then, in the hosted page, capture the extra parameter and pass to lock configuration option.

```
   //Access the addtional parameters in the hosted login page like below
    console.log(config.extraParams.allow_login);

allowLogin: config.extraParams.allow_login
```

https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11/configuration#allowlogin-boolean-

Comment: As I said I am not using Auth0 Lock

Comment: @jay, I understand you are not using lock, you are using auth0-js in your app. However, Hosted login page uses lock internally where you can use the lock configuration. For that reason, I showed how to pass extra parameter using webauth.authorize() method. Could you share code snippet how you initiate login flow?

Comment: ok got it thanks but I ended up creating my own UI and to be honest I liked that approach as UI theme matches my app and I have more control